# How to get rid of the hover zoom in WooCommerce single products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I'm trying to get rid of the function where users can hover over the main product image and zoom into the product. I tried using this code, which has been confirmed by others to work, but nothing changed.

```
function remove_image_zoom_support() {
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_image_zoom_support', 100 );
```

Is this because some other function I'm using is interfering with it?

Here is my functions file:

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

  $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

  wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
  array( $parent_style ),
  wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
  );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'my-google-fonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lekton', false );

}

//* Redirect archive pages to the home page
function redirect_to_home( $query ){
    if(is_archive() ) {
         wp_redirect( home_url() );
         exit;
     }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'redirect_to_home' );

//* Add CPT taxonomy terms to body class
function add_taxonomy_to_single( $classes ) {
  if ( is_single() ) {
    global $post;
    $my_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'skill' );
    if ( $my_terms && ! is_wp_error( $my_terms ) ) {
      foreach ($my_terms as $term) {
        $classes[] = $term->slug;
      }
    }
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_taxonomy_to_single' );

//* Add page slug body class
function add_slug_body_class( $classes ) {
  global $post;

  if ( isset( $post ) ) {
    $classes[] = $post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name;
  }

  return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_slug_body_class' );

//* Unload Gutenberg Block Editor
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'wps_deregister_styles', 100 );
function wps_deregister_styles() {
  wp_dequeue_style( 'wp-block-library' );
}

//* Use Google's jQuery
add_action('init', 'use_jquery_from_google');

function use_jquery_from_google () {
    if (is_admin()) {
        return;
    }

    global $wp_scripts;
    if (isset($wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver)) {
        $ver = $wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver;
    } else {
        $ver = '3.4.0';
    }

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/$ver/jquery.min.js", false, $ver);
}

//* Remove Testimonials post type
add_action( 'init', 'remove_testimonial_cpt', 1000 );

function remove_testimonial_cpt() {
  unregister_post_type( 'testimonial' );
}

//* Remove WYSIWYG editor from products
add_action('init', 'init_remove_support',100);
function init_remove_support(){
    $post_type = 'product';
    remove_post_type_support( $post_type, 'editor');
}

//* Change gallery thumbnail sizes
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_gallery_thumbnail', function( $size ) {
  return array(
    'width' => 132,
    'height' => 162,
    'crop' => 0,
  );
});

//* Remove Proceed to Checkout button on Cart page
remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout',
'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20);

//* Remove thumbnails from Cart page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', '__return_false' );

//* Remove results count and dropdown on main shop page
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );

//* Remove additional information tab on single shop page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_remove_product_tabs', 98 );

function woo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    unset( $tabs['additional_information'] ); 
    return $tabs;
}

//* Add gallery captions for shop items
function gcw_insert_captions( $html, $attachment_id ) {
  $captions = '';
  $title = get_post_field( 'post_title', $attachment_id );
  if( !empty( $title ) ) {
    $captions .= '<h3>' . esc_html( $title ) . '</h3>';
  }
  if( !empty( $captions ) ) {
    $captions = '<div class="gcw-caption">' . $captions . '</div>';

    $html = preg_replace('~<\/div>$~', $captions . '</div>', $html );
  }
  return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'gcw_insert_captions', 10, 2 );

//* Remove hover zoom
function remove_image_zoom_support() {
  remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_image_zoom_support', 100 );

?>
```

If not, what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is possible using `woocommerce_single_product_zoom_enabled` dedicated filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_zoom_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

---

It is possible using `woocommerce_single_product_zoom_enabled` dedicated filter hook.

> The hook **undocumented available parameters** in the options array are:
>
> ```
> $zoom_options = array (
>     'url' => false,
>     'callback' => false,
>     'target' => false,
>     'duration' => 120, // Transition in milli seconds (default is 120)
>     'on' => 'mouseover', // other options: grab, click, toggle (default is mouseover)
>     'touch' => true, // enables a touch fallback
>     'onZoomIn' => false,
>     'onZoomOut' => false,
>     'magnify' => 1, // Zoom magnification: (default is 1  |  float number between 0 and 1)
> );
> ```

Usage with `woocommerce_single_product_zoom_options` filter hook:

1) **Disable the zoom**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_zoom_options', 'custom_single_product_zoom_options', 10, 3 );
function custom_single_product_zoom_options( $zoom_options ) {
    // Disable zoom magnify:
    $zoom_options['magnify'] = 0;

    return $zoom_options;
}
```

2) **Change zoom event option**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_zoom_options', 'custom_single_product_zoom_options', 10, 3 );
function custom_single_product_zoom_options( $zoom_options ) {
    // Changing the zoom event option:
    $zoom_options['on'] = 'click';

    return $zoom_options;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Related: [Adjusting product image's Zoom magnification factor in woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584936/adjusting-product-images-zoom-magnification-factor-in-woocommerce-3/53585353#53585353)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know all these existed. Thank you. Is there a way to disable the click as well? I don't want users to zoom or click the image to open the gallery, either.

Comment: For now, as a hacky solution, I changed `on` to `toggle` and hid the zoom button with css.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to disable the zoom and also have the featured image trigger the lightbox. Someone gave me this code and it worked.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_wc_gallery_lightbox', 100 );
function add_wc_gallery_lightbox() { 
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable gallery zoom and prevent loading `jquery.zoom.js` lib

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_zoom_enabled', '__return_false');
add_action('after_setup_theme', function () {
  global $_wp_theme_features;
  unset($_wp_theme_features['wc-product-gallery-zoom']);
});
```