# Get rid of product images mobile swipe functionality from WooCommerce single product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

On mobile, is there a way to remove the function that allows you to swipe with your finger to scroll through the product images?

I just want users to be able to touch the thumbnails and have the main image show.

Answer (score 1):

Everything required is located on [`Class WC_Frontend_Scripts` source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Frontend_Scripts.html#13-607):

To target mobile devices, you can use the WordPress conditional tag **`wp_is_mobile()`**.

**A) For the Photoswipe functionality** you have essentially 2 hooks:

- `woocommerce_single_product_photoswipe_enabled` to disable it.
- `woocommerce_single_product_photoswipe_options` to change options *(see below)*.

**1) To disable it**, you will use:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_photoswipe_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

or targeting mobile devices *(with touch screen)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_photoswipe_enabled', function(){
    if( wp_is_mobile() )
        return false;
});
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

**2) to change options:**

> The `woocommerce_single_product_photoswipe_options` hook available parameters are:
>
> ```
> array(
>     'shareEl'               => false,
>     'closeOnScroll'         => false,
>     'history'               => false,
>     'hideAnimationDuration' => 0,
>     'showAnimationDuration' => 0,
> )
> ```
>
> You can open related JS files from woocommerce plugin to see how it work (or more options):
>   - `assets/js/photoswipe/photoswipe-ui-default.js`
>   - `assets/js/photoswipe/photoswipe.js`

---

**B) For Flexslider functionality**  you have essentially 2 hooks:

- `woocommerce_single_product_flexslider_enabled` to disable it.
- `woocommerce_single_product_carousel_options` to change options *(see below)*.

**1) To disable it**, you will use:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_flexslider_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

or targeting mobile devices *(with touch screen)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_flexslider_enabled', function(){
    if( wp_is_mobile() )
        return false;
});
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

**2) to change options:**

> The `woocommerce_single_product_carousel_options` hook available parameters are:
>
> ```
> array(
>     'rtl'            => is_rtl(),
>     'animation'      => 'slide',
>     'smoothHeight'   => true,
>     'directionNav'   => false,
>     'controlNav'     => 'thumbnails',
>     'slideshow'      => false,
>     'animationSpeed' => 500,
>     'animationLoop'  => false, // Breaks photoswipe pagination if true.
>     'allowOneSlide'  => false,
> )
> ```
>
> You can open related JS files from woocommerce plugin to see how it work (or more options):
>   - `assets/js/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js`

---

**To change options** you can refer to this similar answer thread: 
[How to get rid of the hover zoom in WooCommerce single products](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/338280/how-to-get-rid-of-the-hover-zoom-in-woocommerce-single-products/338287#338287)

Comment: I tried the two options in A1 to disable Photoswipe, but nothing changed. I'm still able to swipe the main image and have it go through the thumbnails.

Comment: @Desi I will investigate that deeper...