# How to disable hover zoom on woocommerce. None of the common methods work

Tags: plugins, functions, images, css

I have tried these codes in child functions and style files. Nothing works.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'divikingdom_disable_wc_zoom', 99 );
function divikingdom_disable_wc_zoom() {
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
}
```

And this, in Style.css

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery__image {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

And also this (after someone said of doing some magic with "hooks"

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_zoom_enabled', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_zoom_options', 'custom_single_product_zoom_options', 10, 3 );
function custom_single_product_zoom_options( $zoom_options ) {
    // Disable zoom magnify:
    $zoom_options['magnify'] = 0;

    return $zoom_options;
}
```

I tried my luck by changing the hook from false to true.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_zoom_enabled', '__return_true' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_zoom_options', 'custom_single_product_zoom_options', 10, 3 );
function custom_single_product_zoom_options( $zoom_options ) {
    // Disable zoom magnify:
    $zoom_options['magnify'] = 0;

    return $zoom_options;
}
```

And this

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_remove_product_zoom', 11 );

function custom_remove_product_zoom() {
  remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
}
```

Other functions in the child theme works fine. My theme is OceanWp.
All themes and plugins are updated.

Comment: Questions about third-party plugins/services should be asked on the official support pages, as they are [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Is this OceanWP or WooCommerce functionality? You should talk to whoever it comes from. Or to fix this yourself you should find the code that's actually implementing it.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/338280/how-to-get-rid-of-the-hover-zoom-in-woocommerce-single-products